# Application is crashing when I am not using free()

Tags: c, malloc

The application crashes when trying to initialize variables after using malloc().

Using free(), or placing the faulty block of code on top of the other 2, solves all the issues, but why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER startTime, endTime, ticksPerSecond;
    int a = 10000;
    int b = 25000;
    float *allocazione;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&ticksPerSecond);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTime);
    allocazione = (float*)malloc(a*b*sizeof(float));
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTime);
    printf("Tempo di allocazione con malloc : \n%g\n", (double)(endTime.QuadPart - startTime.QuadPart)/(double)ticksPerSecond.QuadPart);

    free(allocazione); //Commenting this causes the application to crash. Why?

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTime);
    allocazione = (float*)calloc(a*b,sizeof(float));
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTime);
    printf("Tempo di allocazione con calloc : \n%g\n", (double)(endTime.QuadPart - startTime.QuadPart)/(double)ticksPerSecond.QuadPart);

    free(allocazione); //Commenting this causes the application to crashes. Why?

    //Having the piece of code on top solves all the issues. Why?
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTime);
    allocazione = (float*)malloc(a*b*sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        *(allocazione + i * b + j) = 0.0f; //Application crash!!!
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTime);
    printf("Tempo di allocazione con malloc + for loop per inizializzare : \n%g\n", (double)(endTime.QuadPart - startTime.QuadPart)/(double)ticksPerSecond.QuadPart);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you're returning the allocated memory back to the operating system once you no longer need it.  That's what you're supposed to do in C.

Comment: You might want to check the result of `malloc` to see if it's NULL. The manual page for `malloc` explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your allocations is for 250 million `float`s, requiring a solid gigabyte of memory. Odds are, you're building a 32 bit application, and that means you only have 2 GB (maybe 3 GB for special OS config) worth of user virtual memory address space.

By failing to `free`, you're trying to allocate three blocks of 1 GB a piece, which won't fit; one of the `malloc` or `calloc` calls are likely failing, and you're not checking the return value so you don't even see it. When you try to use the `NULL` return from the failed allocation, you crash.

Comment: Note: Even if you are building a 64 bit application, it might still fail if your system doesn't have 3+ GB of RAM + pagefile space left over after what the OS and other applications are claiming.

Comment: But by simply having the third malloc on top, all 3 work, even if I remove all free() calls. Wouldn't it still be 1 GB a piece? Is it because of the manual initialization?

Comment: @ihgyug: How do you know they work? The other two don't read or write their memory (`calloc` would if it were a small allocation out of blocks already in use by the allocator, but for big allocations, it requests memory straight from the OS, which comes pre-zeroed, and most `calloc` implementations take advantage of this fact to avoid zeroing the memory at all); they could be returning `NULL` and nothing in your code would ever notice.